# OAuth2 provider No Session found for current thread HibernateException

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am setting up an OAuth2 provider in my groovy grails project. I can access the url but I always get a `401 Unauthorized` error when I try to send a post request to `/oauth/token` The request goes as follows:
`http://localhost:8080/test/oauth/token?username=user&password=password&scope=read&grant_type=password&client_id=client-id`

I've followed the [grails documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/latest/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html) for setting up the Oauth provider. But when I try to do the post request I get an error in my console No `Session found for current thread` now I have no idea where this comes from.  error. Here is the hibernate error:

```
XNIO-1 task-3  2021-06-23 11:12:32,715 ERROR c.s.i.StandardInterceptor StandardInterceptor before: No Session found for current thread  org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsSessionContext.currentSession(GrailsSessionContext.java:112) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5-7.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
...
```

I've tried multiple different filterchains. And I've added the link to my url_public but it gave me a `404 not found` So I settled on not putting in in the url_public and I got these filterchain:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        [pattern: '/oauth/token',               filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter'],
        [pattern: '/securedOAuth2Resources/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter'],
        [pattern: '/**',                        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter,-statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2ExceptionTranslationFilter']
]
```

These are my staticrules:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        [pattern: '/oauth/authorize',           access: "(request.getMethod().equals('GET') or request.getMethod().equals('POST'))"],
        [pattern: '/oauth/token',               access: "request.getMethod().equals('POST')"],
]
```

Futhermore I checked in the database if the OAuthClient table was there and if I had an entry (From the bootstrap.groovy file that initiates an OAuthClient like this:)

```
 new OAuthClient(
                clientId: 'client-id',
                authorizedGrantTypes: ['refresh_token', 'password', 'client_credentials'],
                authorities: ['ROLE_CLIENT'],
                scopes: ['read', 'write'],
        ).save(flush: true)
```

Comment: Can we get some more stacktrace?